# div under another one in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, division

I work on a jsfiddle project and can't find the solution to put my left background image div under my right menu div in responsive mode.

At this time, my background image div stay on top, under my menu div.

Here is my link: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/msnsscjb/1/)

SCREENSHOT

(1 ) this what I have and ( 2 ) what I want

[image][image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.total {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%
}

.dessus {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background: #EEF;
}

.spaceone {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  display: block
}

.sub-spaceone {
  margin: 0px 50px 50px 50px;
  display: block;
}

.space {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  display: block
}

.pos {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.dessous {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: url(http://www.work.booclin.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Unknown-7.jpeg) no-repeat top center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .total {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dessous {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dessus {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
  .pos {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: none;
    margin: 30px 50px;
  }
  .spaceone {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: block
  }
  .sub-spaceone {
    display: none
  }
  .space {
    margin: 0px 30px 30px 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .pos {
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .spaceone {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .space {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    display: inline;
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:300px) {
  .pos {
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .spaceone {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .space {
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="total">


  <div class="dessus">

    <div class="pos">
      <span class="spaceone">Title</span>
      <span class="sub-spaceone">Sub-Title</span>
      <span class="space">Menu 1</span>
      <span class="space">Menu 2</span>
      <span class="space">Menu 3</span>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="dessous"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While having a fiddle is a nice thing that help us understand your issue better, you must also include the code **in your question** - That's why when you posted it you had to put it as "code" to trick the system (You can also create a stack snippet - you'll find it in the buttons in the tooltip of the editor)

Comment: I did it ;D @AlonEitan

Comment: You need to image to be **under** the menu, and and not **below** it in responsive mode?

Comment: @AlonEitan I want my image under the menu, but at this time if you check my code, we can't see model hairs. because menu is on the image

Comment: You can play with `background-position: right 30% top;` in your media queries.

Comment: @AlonEitan check my updated question, i added screenshots ;D

Comment: Remove the `fixed` - `.dessous { background: url(http://www.work.booclin.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Unknown-7.jpeg) no-repeat top center;}`

Comment: Great @AlonEitan it will not be a problem for fullscreen, because it works perfectly now ;D

Comment: Cool. So it solved your problem? You're fine with that solution?

Comment: yep it's ok for me ;D put it as a answer if you want, i will validate it

Comment: Well, @athimohan already did it so you can accept their answer if you find it helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed fixed from .dessous:

```
.dessous {
    background: url(http://www.work.booclin.ovh/wpcontent/uploads/2017/04/Unknown-7.jpeg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.total {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%
}

.dessus {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background: #EEF;
}

.spaceone {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  display: block
}

.sub-spaceone {
  margin: 0px 50px 50px 50px;
  display: block;
}

.space {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  display: block
}

.pos {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.dessous {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: url(http://www.work.booclin.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Unknown-7.jpeg) no-repeat top center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .total {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dessous {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dessus {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
  .pos {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: none;
    margin: 30px 50px;
  }
  .spaceone {
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: block
  }
  .sub-spaceone {
    display: none
  }
  .space {
    margin: 0px 30px 30px 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .pos {
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .spaceone {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .space {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    display: inline;
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:300px) {
  .pos {
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .spaceone {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .space {
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="total">


  <div class="dessus">

    <div class="pos">
      <span class="spaceone">Title</span>
      <span class="sub-spaceone">Sub-Title</span>
      <span class="space">Menu 1</span>
      <span class="space">Menu 2</span>
      <span class="space">Menu 3</span>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="dessous"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should also explain what you changed that made it worked. I see that you removed `fixed` so you must explain that it prevent the background to scroll with the rest of the page (i.e - It's fixed on the same position relative to the page)

Comment: The background-attachment was set to fixed which means it will go behind the navbar and will be fixed while scrolling.